# how to store and manage user's images in a website

Tags: php, image, image-uploading, image-upload

I'm creating a dating site where users could upload their images,
some private and some public.

What I planned to do is to save all the uploaded images, and when I would like to show them I will have a script that will call them.

ie: url-> mysite.com/members/mainimage/5

the function that handles this call is:
    public function mainImage($user) {

```
    $this->load->model('tables/user_images_table');
    $image = $this->user_images_table->getMainUserImage($user);

    if($image != null ) {
        $imageExploded = explode('.',$image);

        switch( $imageExploded[1] ) {
            case "gif": $ctype="image/gif"; break;
            case "png": $ctype="image/png"; break;
            case "jpeg":
            case "jpg": $ctype="image/jpg"; break;
            default:
        }
        $imagePath = 'uploads/'.$image;
    } else {
        //default image
        $imagePath = 'inner/default.png';
        $ctype = 'image/png';
    }



    header('Content-type: '.$ctype);
    readfile(base_url()."images/".$imagePath);
}
```

but after I see my site is getting bigger,
I notice that each user image request all my appliaction files are loaded, and it probably will slow my site down.

do you have any idea how to save private images (that wont will be public by url, only after some checks on the user)

Comment: For example Facebook: it uses random-long-name for images, that you can't easily predict the pattern.

Answer (score 2):

store your private images in some folder, also place there `.htaccess` with such code:

```
deny from all
```

so now no one can access these files via http directly

then create `.htaccess` in the root of your site and copy these lines there:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^private-photo/([0-9]+)\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png)$ private_photo.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

so now all http requests like http://site.com/private-photo/113.jpg will be redirected to private_photo.php

so the final step is: you create private_photo.php where you get id of image from `$_GET["id"]`, make security checkings - if the user who requests the photo has an access to it, and then `fopen/fpassthru` the image or just displaying an error about restricted access